spring-integration-sftp flow runs randomly after first schedule
a spring-integrations-sftp configuration like below
   @Bean
   public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory() {
        final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false);
        factory.setHost("a-host");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("username");
        factory.setTimeout(30000);
        factory.setPrivateKey("private-key-location");
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase("passphrase");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabasePollSkipStrategy testIncomingDatabasePollSkipStrategy(final DaoService daoService) {
        return new DatabasePollSkipStrategy(daoService, "samplePoller");
    }

    @Bean
    public PollSkipAdvice testIncomingPollSkipAdvice(final DatabasePollSkipStrategy testIncomingDatabasePollSkipStrategy) {
        return new PollSkipAdvice(testIncomingDatabasePollSkipStrategy);
    }

    @Bean
    public ChainFileListFilter<SftpClient.DirEntry> testIncomingChainFileListFilter(final ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore) {
        final ChainFileListFilter<SftpClient.DirEntry> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter("a-regex"));
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, "a-prefix"));

        return chainFileListFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler testTaskScheduler() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("A-Task-Scheduler");

        return taskScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testIncomingIntegrationFlow(final ChainFileListFilter<SftpClient.DirEntry> testIncomingChainFileListFilter,
                                                       final SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sessionFactory,
                                                       final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler testTaskScheduler,
                                                       final PollSkipAdvice testIncomingPollSkipAdvice) {
        final List<AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
        optionList.add(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.PRESERVE_TIMESTAMP);
        optionList.add(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.DELETE);

        final PollerSpec pollerSpec = getTestPollerSpec(testTaskScheduler, testIncomingPollSkipAdvice);

        return IntegrationFlow.from(() -> new GenericMessage<>("/a-remote-directory"), e -> e.poller(pollerSpec))
                .split()
                .log(message -> "1- LS.getPayload (Flow: test, Source: a-prefix) -> " + message.getPayload())
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sessionFactory,
                                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS, "payload")
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE,
                                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY)
                )
                .split()
                .log(message -> "2- MGET.getPayload (Flow: test, Source: a-prefix)-> " + message.getPayload())
                .handle(Sftp
                        .outboundGateway(sessionFactory, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "'"
                                + "/a-remote-directory" + "' + payload")
                        .options(optionList.toArray(new AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option[0]))
                        .filter(testIncomingChainFileListFilter)
                        .localDirectoryExpression("'" + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator +
                                "a-local-working-directory" + File.separator
                                + "a-prefix" + "' + #remoteDirectory")
                        .temporaryFileSuffix(FILE_SUFFIX)
                        .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                        .fileExistsMode(REPLACE)
                )
                .handle(message -> fileService.handleMessage("a-prefix", "test", message))
                .get();
    }

    private PollerSpec getTestPollerSpec(final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler testTaskScheduler,
                                         final PollSkipAdvice testIncomingPollSkipAdvice) {
        return Pollers.cron("0 */15 * ? * *")
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(50)
                .advice(testIncomingPollSkipAdvice)
                .taskExecutor(testTaskScheduler);
    }

starts to execute at */15 but after that I can also see that "1- LS.getPayload (Flow: test, Source: a-prefix)" logs randomly and another execution starts, which is a bit weird. Because at this random executions, it does not arrive to the debug point in org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger#nextExecution or org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable#run.
On the */15 executions, it stops at the debug points. What can trigger the flow apart from polling adapter?
logs:
2024-11-27T15:45:00.055Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler5]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T15:48:31.471Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler3]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T15:49:58.583Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler5]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T15:53:04.676Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler3]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T15:54:26.647Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler5]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T15:57:34.112Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler3]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T15:58:56.226Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler5]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T16:00:00.088Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler2]: 1- LS.getPayload...
2024-11-27T16:03:15.977Z  INFO 24160 - [Task-Scheduler3]: 1- LS.getPayload...

these two (2024-11-27T15:45:00.055Z and 2024-11-27T16:00:00.088Z) make sense but the others do not.
UPDATE (29 Nov 24): Actually traversal is looping for every thread. Whenever the thread-N finishes its traversal, the flow is starting to traverse the given path again on that thread.

it is just because of the maxMessagesPerPoll(50). Since this has been given to the new GenericMessage<>, it produces 50 "/a-remote-directory/" messages per poll, so the max message per poll should be 1 for recursive LS for sFTP file listing.
